# Is it possible for Emacs to show Erlang functions arity in echo area like for Elisp functions?

Tags: emacs, erlang

I've installed and configured Erlang language in my Emacs dotfiles, mostly following this guide: https://erlang-ls.github.io/editors/emacs/

But I'm just starting in Erlang and I don't really know how a Erlang development environment looks like, so I'm not sure if things "missing" aren't part of the Erlang development environment or if it's something I have configured wrong.

This is my current configuration: https://github.com/jacksonbenete/.emacs.d/blob/main/lm-emacs/languages/erlang.el

I don't have functions completions, it asks for a "tags-table" and I don't know what it is or where I can find it.

Also, I don't receive any hints in the echo-area, this would be very useful and it's my main question since I can live without completion.

Just like I can start writing a function in Lisp and receive some hints of arity and parameters in the echo area/minibuffer, can I receive the same hints while writing Erlang?

Maybe my lsp-server isn't configured correctly?

Or this is not something implemented for Erlang-mode and Erlang-ls?

[image: Example of what I'm looking for]

Answer (score 1):

[edts](https://github.com/sebastiw/edts) is the way to go with emacs, it has autocomplete and code navigation. Originally I was using [distel](https://github.com/massemanet/distel), but after [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaGrIJGhrGQ&t=626s) I switched to edts

I compiled it with [erlang 23.0](https://github.com/sebastiw/edts/blob/master/.travis.yml#L4-L6), but once it is compiled, I develop on other versions without problems, like currently I'm using [erlang 24.0](https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases/tag/OTP-24.0)

For managing different erlang versions on my system, I'm using [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl)

This is my personal [emacs configuration](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rorra/ecf2bf001b9c292766e32b64655923d1/raw/1daf469dd2e00ecb6a35facb612564be2237ecd3/.emacs), I got most of it from internet and then I did personal customizations

Other than that, I use the templates that came with the [erlang mode](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.el.html) a lot (tempo-template-erlang-*)